# Can I use twice "@subpackage" for phpDocumentor?

Tags: php, documentation, comments, package, phpdoc

For example I have a project called "myproj" and a subpackage called "utils" and in this subpackage there's again a subpackage called "debug".

Can I do something like that: ?

```
/**
  * @package myproj
  * @subpackage utils
  * @subpackage debug
  * /
```

Thanks in advance!

---

***Solution***

There is also the tag @category:

> The @category tag is used to organize groups of packages together.

So you can use the tags in the following order: @category, @package, @subpackage
And if that isn't enough for you, can could use also underscores in the names.

Comment: I suggest you to use @subpackage Utils_Debug if you use such namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know the question is quite old, but for any google speeders - **`@subpackage` tags are now deprecated**. Use `@package` tag instead in a following manner:

```
@package [level 1]\[level 2]\[etc.]
```

Check PHPDocumentor2 manual: http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/phpdoc/tags/package.html

Comment: Wow - an answer after more than 3 years! Thank you.

Comment: No prob, I was searching for some info about PHPD2 myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Most generators will not understand multiple subpackage tags. Convention is either to use underscores or hyphens; or not segmenting below 2 levels (package / subpackage)

See: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.subpackage.pkg.html

Comment: Thanks, but I've found the tag "category".
So I use @category, @package and optionally @subpackage. That are enough for me ;)